# Sending smart notifications to Garmin Connect IQ apps

Tags: notifications, garmin, connectiq

Ive just purchased a Garmin Fenix 3 GPS watch and Im interested in sending notifications to the watch from an app Im writing for Android phones (to display new chat message notifications on the watch). Is there any way to send notifications to the watch (similar to the "smart notifications" supported by Garmins own Garmin Connect Androd APP that pop up for incoming calls/sms) without creating a Connect IQ app for the watch?

If its not possible to send notifications to the watch without creating a Connect IQ app, can the Connect IQ app be woken up and put in the foreground by a notification from the Android app or does the Connect IQ app have to be running in the foreground to be able to receive notifications?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to let the application send a notification to android, and then from within the Garmin Connect app allow those notifications to be pushed Fenix 3